# How to use attribute routing in for get method with same parameter in web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

**following is code for calling web API call**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> RequisitionNameByQuantityThisDraw()
{
    //Guid applicationRequisitionOid

    string userName = string.Empty;
    SessionObject sessionData = new SessionObject().GetSessionData();
    if (sessionData == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Login");
    }
    Guid aa = new Guid("41CF8843-2AF4-40D0-9998-D6D516367A7D");
    HttpResponseMessage response = _HttpClient.GetAsync("api/ApplicationSIRMeasure/RequisitionNameByQuantity?applicationRequisitionOid=" + aa).Result;

    string userJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Json(userJsonString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**below is web API methods**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid applicationRequisitionOid)
{
    var result = _IService.GetAll(applicationRequisitionOid);
    if (result == null)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No data found");
    else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}   

[Route("api/ApplicationSIRMeasure/RequisitionNameByQuantity/{applicationRequisitionOid:Guid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage RequisitionNameByQuantity(Guid applicationRequisitionOid)
{
    Guid id = new Guid("41CF8843-2AF4-40D0-9998-D6D516367A7D");
    var result = _IService.GetRequisitionByQunatityThisDraw(id);
    if (result == null)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No data found");
    else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

whenever I call this web API with above code it goes to first get method.
but I won't to call in a second method

Comment: What is the `[Route]` attribute above the first method (`Get(Guid applicationRequisitionOid)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route on the Web API is

```
[Route("api/ApplicationSIRMeasure/RequisitionNameByQuantity/{applicationRequisitionOid:guid}")]
```

Yet the request is calling

```
"api/ApplicationSIRMeasure/RequisitionNameByQuantity?applicationRequisitionOid="
```

Because the url does not match the second route template it is finding a match on the other action because the query string parameter matches.

you need to update the URL being called to match the route template of the target action.

```
var aa = new Guid("41CF8843-2AF4-40D0-9998-D6D516367A7D");
var url = string.Format("api/ApplicationSIRMeasure/RequisitionNameByQuantity/{0}", aa);
var response = await _HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
```

I really do not see the need to create the `Guid` when you can just build the URL with the same string that was used to create the `Guid` instance